# Jump to function definition in Emacs by mouse-click

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

Using Emacs + Common Lisp (SBCL) + Slime, is there a quick way to jump to the definition of a function (defun ...) without typing (find-function) the name of the function?
I am looking for an similar solution as often provided in Eclipse: 
Strg + (left-mouse-click on function call).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyboard. Usually <kbd>m-.</kbd> or <kbd>esc-.</kbd> in Emacs. The cursor must be on the symbol.

Answer (score 3):

In Emacs:

With point on the function whose definition you want to visit, hit `C-x 5 F` (`find-function-other-frame`).

You can also bind `find-function`, `find-function-other-window`, or `find-function-other-frame` to a mouse button action.

You mention *Strg + (left-mouse-click on function call)*, for instance.  Dunno what `Strg` is here, but you can easily bind `[mouse-1]` or `[down-mouse-1]` to a command that checks the symbol at the click position, and if it is a defined function calls `find-function` for it, and if it is not has the usual `[mouse-1]` or `[down-mouse-1]` behavior.

Personally, I wouldn't want such behavior, but it is easy to achieve in Emacs.  For example:

```el
(defun my-find-func-mouse (event)
  (interactive "e")
  (let ((fn  (save-excursion
               (goto-char (posn-point (event-end event)))
               (function-called-at-point))))
    (unless (fboundp fn) (error "No function here"))
    (find-function-do-it fn nil 'switch-to-buffer-other-window)))

(global-set-key [C-down-mouse-1] nil)
(global-set-key [C-mouse-1] #'my-find-func-mouse)
```

Comment: @BRPocock: I see. OP: In that case, just bind `[C-mouse-1]` or `[C-down-mouse-1]`. (And why not use the Emacs convention, `C-`, here instead of the German `Strg`?)

Comment: Yes, sorry _Strg_ was supposed to be _Ctrl_. The weird thing is, that (find-function) does not find any function in my source file (I added the source folder to 'load-path' variable). Do the lisp files have to have the .el / .elc file-ending in order to use _find-function_? All my source code is located in _.lisp_ files.

Comment: That's a different question ("Why doesn't `find-function` work for me?"). Pose it separately, providing a step-by-step recipe, preferably starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file), so we can help by understanding your context & what you are doing. Try starting from `emacs -Q`, reading `C-h f find-function`. That tells you the function must be in a Lisp file in your `load-path` or `find-function-source-path`. See also function `symbol-file`, which is usually ultimately used for cases like this: it checks `load-history`. In general, the function needs to be autoloaded or needs to have been loaded.

Comment: Thanks! I posed a new [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964283/emacs-search-space-for-find-function)

Comment: I added code for a mouse-click command, which I think answers *this* question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is to create a TAGS file using etags:

```
$ find . -type f -iname "*.lisp*" | etags -
```

Then, do `M-x visit-tags-table` and navigate to the TAGS file. After the tags are loaded, you can simply do `M-.` with point on function and it will open in the current buffer.

Also, you can use `M-*` to go back to where you were before.

If you're using projectile, you can simply keep your TAGS file in the project root and you won't need to run `M-x visit-tags-table`. Projectile will load the tags table automatically when you first press `M-.`

Comment: In my experience there is no need to use tags at all to use `M-.` (slime-edit-definition) in Common Lisp & Slime. Then to go back in Slime it's `M-,` (comma).