# Emacs: Search-Space for Find-Function

Tags: emacs, elisp

Working on my first **sbcl** project in **slime** mode, I have trouble with setting up emacs properly for navigating within my code: Often, I would like to jump to the function definition (to any custom function within my source code) of a function. Therefore *find-function* seems to be a good starting point. Unfortunately, ***find-function* never finds any of my functions**: [No match]! My source code is located in a simple file like *geometry.lisp* with function definitions like:

```
    (defun get-right-normal(vector)
       "Computes right-normal of given vector"
       (make-2d-vector :x (* -1 (2d-vector-y vector)) :y (2d-vector-x vector)))
```

I added the path of the source file to the 'load-path variable:

```
    (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/src")
```

The description of *find-function* says

```
The library where FUNCTION is defined is searched for in
`find-function-source-path', if non-nil, otherwise in `load-path'.
```

But trying to set *`find-function-source-path* by

```
    (add-to-list 'find-function-source-path "/path/to/src")
```

returns

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: find-function-source-path
```

How can I set the value of this variable? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what does this have to do with SLIME and SBCL? If you want to use SLIME and SBCL,read the SLIME manual. It has a chapter on finding definitions. If you want to find elisp definitions, read the Emacs docs...

Answer (score 0):

You must define things before you can ask for their values. The error message tells you that variable `find-functions-source-path` is not defined. Why? Because you have not loaded the library that defines it. You need to load library `find-func.el[c]`: **`(require 'find-func)`**.

Comment: Thanks! I can now set the variable correctly, but _find-function_ still doesn't find any of my functions. Do I miss something important? I'm new to emacs and lisp, so this is a whole new story for me....

Comment: No, thats exactly what i asked for: why doesn't _find-function_ find any of my functions? Setting the _find-functions-source-path_ was just my own attempt solving the problem, but it didn't.

Comment: My bad. I thought that your comment here was added to the [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30802346/729907), which I think has now been answered.

Comment: Have you in fact loaded `find-func.el`? I don't think so. If you had then I don't think you would get that error, assuming that your version of that file defines that variable.

Comment: Well, I added _(require 'find-func)_ and
_(add-to-list 'find-function-source-path "/path/to/src")_ to my .el startup file and I don't get an error. But still none of my functions are being found by _find-function_

Comment: Have you in fact loaded the file that defines the function that you expect `find-function` to be able to find? Your question is not very clear - try providing a step-by-step recipe that starts from `emacs -Q`. Try loading `find-func.el` (not `.elc`) and `M-x debug-on-entry find-definition-noselect`, and step through the debugger to see why that function is not finding your definition.

Comment: I think the point that has not been addressed by any of these comments is the fact that the code OP is interested in is *Common Lisp*, not Elisp. `find-func` is for finding *Elisp* code definitions, using Elisp mechanisms such as `load-path`, is it not?

Comment: @PhilHudson: The question is about Elisp. E.g., *"How can I set the value of this variable?"* The user wants to use SLIME - OK. But this question is about using `find-func`.